# Find all functions $f(x)$ whose third derivative is identically zero.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

To evaluate the solution, I integrated the equation $f'''(x)=0$ thrice, which yields $f(x)$ as a quadratic polynomial (with zero as a permissible coefficient for all the terms).

My questions are:

> Is this the only type of function whose third derivative vanishes?

I was wondering if there was a possibility of other functions (trigonometric, logarithmic, exponential, or even non-elementary) that exhibit this property.

If the only permissible solution is a quadratic or lower degree polynomial, I would like a proof which rules out the possibility of any other function to exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: The antiderivative of a function is unique up to a constant.

Comment: What is the domain of the function?

Comment: So the uniqueness of this solution is guaranteed by this theorem alone?

Comment: Starting from $f''' = 0$ and integrating thrice, you showed that it was necessary for $f$ to be an at most quadratic polynomial, right? Note that it is also sufficient.

Comment: @Arthur I believe it's the set of all Reals, this question popped up in the first exercise set of MIT's Single Variable Calc

Comment: @KeiOh I suppose yes, but I'm still not convinced about the uniqueness of this solution.

Comment: The Taylor series has to terminate with (at most) the $x^2$ term for this to be true. And that makes the function polynomial, which is equal to its own Taylor series. Any other elementary continuous function, like the ones you mentioned (exponential, trigonometric) etc. have infinite Taylor series expansions so the third derivative (or indeed any $n$th derivative) can never be identically zero.

Comment: @Deepak Point noted, although I'm not yet familiar with Taylor series expansions. They'll be discussed near the end of my current course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence it is the fundamtal theorem of calculus. I marked the points where the theorem is used with a exclamation mark.
$$
f'''(x)=0\\
\Rightarrow \int_a^x f'''(x) dx \stackrel{!}{=} f''(x)-f''(a)= 0\\
\Rightarrow \int_a^x f''(x)-f''(a) dx \stackrel{!}{=} f'(x)-f'(a)-f''(a)(x-a)= 0\\
\Rightarrow \int_a^x  f'(x)-f'(a)-f''(a)(x-a) dx \stackrel{!}{=} f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)-\tfrac{1}{2}f''(a)(x-a)^2= 0\\
\Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\tfrac{1}{2}f''(a)(x-a)^2
$$